# CAML query generator/builder

Tags: sharepoint-2010

i am looking for sharepoint caml query builder function which could take input as field/value/operator/condition and return caml query string with both combinations (AND/OR)

Answer (score 1):

check out these tools

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/458008/CAML-Query-Builder

http://spcamlviewer.codeplex.com/

http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/

hope it helps :) .

Answer (score 0):

The U2U tool link seems to be broken now:

I've found this instead:

About: http://www.sjoukjezaal.com/blog/tool-sharepoint-developers-caml-designer/

Download:
http://sharepoint.biwug.be/SitePages/Caml_Designer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For C#, check out Camlex.NET: http://camlex.codeplex.com/